# background-color of body overflows over body-content in html in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a style issue in Chrome when the screen resolution becomes smaller, the background color of the body rides over the background content and that too happens randomly on various screen sizes.

This issue pops up only in chrome while it is working perfect in Firefox, Safari. My body tag is as follows

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Avenirltstd book;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you add in the CSS of your background content, and maybe a bit of sample HTML?

Comment: Also since this happens randomly, not consistently, you should add a screenshot

Comment: can u send me demo link or screenshot of issue u r facing?

Comment: can you show us a working fiddle or snippet so we can all see